# Why is it ~있어요 and not ~이/가 있어요

Tags: grammar

I have encountered that there is no marker used with 있어요 or 없어요.
The textbooks I have do not give a good explanation for that. So, why is that? And, can you provide some examples of it being used?

Comment: Can you perhaps make your question clearer? For example it would be useful to know what kind of example the textbook gave you. Besides, the verb 있다 has at least three possible meanings depending on usage, so it really might not be clear what exactly you are trying to find out/understand.

Comment: 사과가 있어요, can be written as 사과 있어요. Sometimes, people omit "가" in this case. The question is asking why it is omitted in cases like that. 
I think @Catomic did a good job answering the question without clarification.

Comment: In formal usage, particularly in writing, it is a good idea to include all particles, but in spoken language, 이/가, 을/를, and 은/는 very often get left out...to a lesser extent some others do to.  The usually quoted rule about Korean is:  "If the meaning can be reconstructed, it is ok to leave out any part of an expression" and as you've seen this includes not only these particles but often a lot more...subjects, most pronouns, tense markers, and so on.

Comment: @B.Alvn, I understand. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to know about 있다 and 없다 is that they are two among those few verbs which can have an object 'looking like a second subject' (i.e. taking subject markers).  Compare:

> 나는 너**를** 알아 (from 알다). (I know you.)
>   나는 길**을** 몰라 (from 모르다). (I don't know the way.)

--which is the regular situation in which the objects (너 and 길) take regular object markers (을 and 를).

> 나는 네**가** 좋아 (from 좋다). (I like you.)
>   나는 일**이** 있어 (from 있다). (I have some business to take care of.)
>   나는 돈**이** 없어 (from 없다). (I don't have money.)

--in which the objects (너, 일 and 돈) take subject markers (가 and 이).

(Note: Grammarians can characterize these 'objects' as a '(second) subject' or take any number of theoretical approaches, but I am just calling them an 'object' because that's what they end up looking like when translated to English.)

---

After that, the marking follows all the regular rules, I believe.  Some examples:

You can drop the (first) subject.

> A:  뭐가 문제야? (What's the problem.)
>   B:  (dropped: 나는) 돈이 없어. (There is no money.)

(Note:  Grammarians may characterize '돈이 없어' as consisting of 돈 as subject and 없다 as intransitive verb.)

이/가 may switch to 은/는 for contrast.

> 나는 돈**은** 있는데 시간이 없어. (I have money, but I do not have time.)
>   고기**는** 있는데 야채가 없어. (There is meat, but there is no vegetables.)

Just to be complete, the following are all possible in a contrast. Which sounds most natural would depend on the context.

> 돈**이** 있고 시간**이** 없어.
>   돈**이** 있고 시간**은** 없어.
>   돈**은** 있고 시간**이** 없어.
>   돈**은** 있고 시간**은** 없어.

이/가 may switch to 은/는 for listing.

> 시간**은** 없고 마음**은** 바쁘고. (No money, busy--i.e. anxious--mind.)

---

On dropping the marker altogether, which is your question, that is often the most natural sounding, especially in short spoken exchanges, for example:

> 시간 있어요?

Or

> A: 같이 갈래? (Will you come along?)
>   B: 시간 없어.

To put any marker after 시간 in these may sound strange in most circumstances.  You might put that in for politeness or tentativeness.  If your bossed asked you to come along, you might be more likely to say:

> 시간이 없어요.

In questions you often put 좀 (a bit) to get:

> 시간 좀 있어요?
>   돈 좀 있어요?

Markers are dropped from most descriptive phrases.

> 명함 없는 참석자 (participant without a name card)
>   꾸밈없는 아이 (artless child)

꾸밈없는 has consolidated into a single word.  (So with 재미있다, 관계있다, 변함없다.)

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the markers are omitted for the "natural sound." I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct, but my bet is on that it's not.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you contrasting "money" and "time" in this sentence?  나는 돈은 있는데 시간이 없어.    If that is the case, shouldn't both contrasted nouns be marked with the contrast marker 은/는?   If not, can you explain?

Comment: @B.Alvn. 은/는 is the more express device. Consider saying, 'The boy is not *even* twelve *yet*.' Someone's 'The boy's not twelve' would be less explicit but, in the right situation, convey the same thing. / Is 'shouldn't both' a reference to grammar book grammar? You may be assured that the four permutations (about money and time) would sound equally good to a native speaker though he might have a good reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: @Catomic  I appreciate the feedback, good sir/ma'am.  I only really know what those grammar books say, and what I've seen in 8.5 years...I'm no native or expert.  I guess what I'm really asking about here is "표준말" ....I mean, what is standard usage?

Comment: @B.Alvn. The difference among the four possibilities is not one being more standard than the others. The most 'usual' is probably 은/은. If you say 은/이 it may emphasize the 이 more. (Compare italicizing a block of text. If a word in it is already in italics, we set it back to straight font. This is 'double italicizing' if you follow my meaning.) 이/이 may (but need not) be uttered in a tone of exasperation--as if you gave up on contrast and would give things out singly. It's much better to find an actual utterance and try to account for it than to generate examples out of thin air.